# Lenskit: How to add ratings from arraylist to EvenCollectionDao?

Tags: java, lenskit

I am trying to add the static ratings to `EventCollectionDao`:

```
List<Rating> rs = new ArrayList<>();
    rs.add(org.grouplens.lenskit.data.event.Ratings.make(1, 2, 3));
    EventCollectionDAO dao = new EventCollectionDAO(rs);
```

But it yields this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.grouplens.lenskit.collections.CollectionUtils.fast(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
>   at org.grouplens.lenskit.data.dao.EventCollectionDAO.(EventCollectionDAO.java:58)

Comment: What version(s) of LensKit components are you using? This looks like it is most likely a version mismatch between two LensKit components.

Comment: Okay it's sorted now was using 2 different versions of lenskit.